# How to use IF conditions inside sql UPDATE statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 <?php
session_start();
include('config.php');

$id = $_SESSION['USER_ID'];

$sql = "UPDATE user ";

if($_POST["fname"]!=""){
$sql .="set FIRST_NAME='".$_POST["fname"]."',";
}

if($_POST["lname"]!=""){
$sql .="set LAST_NAME='".$_POST["lname"]."',";
}

if($_POST["email"]!=""){
$sql .="set EMAIL='".$_POST["email"]."',";
}

$sql .="where USER_ID=".$id ;




$result = mysql_query($sql);

    if($result=='1'){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('Details successfully changed!');


        </script>

        <?php
   }else{
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           alert('Error : Data editing');

        </script>

    <?php
    }
```

Above is my code I use to edit details in user table.  I exactly want to check the fields which are filled and then update it into database, but this isn't work, when I echo this $sql it shows this.

```
UPDATE user set FIRST_NAME='test',set LAST_NAME='one',set EMAIL='test@gmail.com',where USER_ID=4
```

So whats the error with my code?

Comment: It isn't obvious by looking at your query?

Comment: Your SQL syntax is wrong.

Comment: You only need `SET` once.  Move it to `$sql = "UPDATE user SET";` and remove it from everywhere else. That doesn't even touch on the other things you're doing wrong though (such as using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions).

Comment: OR SQL injection vulnerability via using raw $_POST. Please take a minute to read http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your SQL is the multiple 'SET' statement.

You can use something like that.

An array to set your values and after you can implode it to seperate it by ", "

```
$id = $_SESSION['USER_ID'];

$setStatement = array();
if($_POST["fname"] != "") { array_push($setStatement, "FIRST_NAME = '".$_POST["fname"]."'"); }
if($_POST["lname"] != "") { array_push($setStatement, "LAST_NAME = '".$_POST["lname"]."'"); }
if($_POST["email"] != "") { array_push($setStatement, "EMAIL = '".$_POST["email"]."'"); }

if(!empty($setStatement)) {
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET " . implode($setStatement, ", ") . " WHERE USER_ID=". $id;
    //print $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: wow it works :) thanks a lot dude (Y) Appriciate your help!! Thanx again.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax will be wrong...

The full syntax will be: `UPDATE user set FIRST_NAME='value', set LAST_NAME='value', set EMAIL='value', where USER_ID=<id>`

But you may not have a comma after the last set. So you the correct syntax should be: `UPDATE user set FIRST_NAME='value', set LAST_NAME='value', set EMAIL='value' where USER_ID=<id>`

By using a if statement, you have to add a comma in your if condition. But what about the first and lastname are empty, in that case you may not.

A option can be to create a array, and use the implode.
For example by using a insert you can do this:

```
<?php

    // array containing data
    $array = array(
       "name" => "John",
       "surname" => "Doe",
       "email" => "j.doe@intelligence.gov"
    );

    // build query...
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO table";

    // implode keys of $array...
    $sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($array))."`)";

    // implode values of $array...
    $sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $array)."') ";

    // execute query...
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

**** Edit
Other way is:

```
$array = array();

if($_POST["firstname"] != "")
{
   $array["FIRST_NAME"] = "value";
}

if($_POST["lastname"] != "")
{
   $array["LAST_NAME"] = "value";
}

if($_POST["email"] != "")
{
   $array["EMAIL"] = "value";
}

$query = "UPDATE user SET ";
$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
   if($counter != 0 && $counter < count($array))
       $query .= ",";
   $query .= $key . "=" . $value;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the correct syntax is `UPDATE user set FIRST_NAME='value', LAST_NAME='value', EMAIL='value' where USER_ID=<id>`

Comment: @bastos.sergio that is mentioned in my post? 3 sentle?